# Conflict in namespaces in WPF Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

I have created a *WPF* project that has the name *Company.System.SomeName*. When I try to build the project, I get several conflict errors in the *xaml* files as the one bellow:

> The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Company.System'.

Is there anyway to solve this conflict or I need to change the project name and exclude the *System* string from it?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you post some code that's producing the error? There is most likely the error line along the error message.

Comment: Not recommended but you can do it.

Comment: @Onur: The conflicts are in the .xaml files. When the compiler tries to interpret the xaml to c# it confuses between the System namespace in .NetFramework and the Company.System namespace in the project.

Comment: If the type is "qualified enough", e.g. `global::System.Windows`, it should work. Altough it's indeed better not to use `System`as part of a namespace.

Comment: @Onur: I need a way to make the objects defined in xaml use a "qualified enough" types...

Comment: Create a namespace-prefix and use it...

Comment: have the same problem with 2 namespaces "Company.Common" and "Common.Controls". global:: would be the solution but the g.i.cs does not contain this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention  global::System in order to use the global namespace to solve the issue.

example

```
using System;

namespace SampleApp.System{

...
`global::System.Windows.Controls.UserControl`
....
}
```

Comment: The conflict is in the xaml files

Comment: It shows that it is in Xaml file but actually its in g.cs files

Comment: Right, but aren't the .g.cs files auto-generated ?

Comment: Yes they are auto generated and so modifying them is not recommended. I would suggest you to change the string "System" to something else if its not mandatory. :)